# Can any one scrap this link using python https://merolagani.com/MarketSummary.aspx?type=losers

Tags: python, web-scraping, web

Please explain it
The code that caused this warning is on line 10 of the file C:\Users/PycharmProjects\merolaganiwebscrap\test5.py.

```
  soup=BeautifulSoup(con.text)
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-index" data-live="losers" data-live-label="#dateLabel" data-live-range="0" data-live-summary="false" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tblSummary">
</table> 



[]
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


# site url
url="https://merolagani.com/MarketSummary.aspx?type=losers"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
# make a get request to fetch the raw html data
con=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(con.text)
table=soup.find('table',class_='table table-striped table-hover table-index')
print(table,"\n\n\n")
headers=[i.text for i in table.find_all('th')]
data=[j for j in table.find_all('tr',{'class':["decrease-row"]})]
result=[{headers[index]:cell.text for index,cell in enumerate(row.find_all('td'))} for row in data]
print(result)

This is my code
```

Comment: Why would anyone want to scrap that website? Also, what didn't you understand about "To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor"?

Comment: Because I'm not able to scap this link

Answer (score 0):

The data you want to get is loaded from different URL via Ajax. To get it you can use next example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url = "https://merolagani.com/signalr/send"

params = {
    "transport": "serverSentEvents",
    "connectionToken": "HSMuYPlsmKSeB_WxvNdIDcHeOX1rU3FlUBLXUY6Z7gztJnHez-tU1S5DrBS2sbmr0iWPz2i8izZOnfKbNC1l_ej6EUwZmhjH8xTt5R1xGyoSYf29-fW8L9Xai2k7x-cAup5TT2pFffFgCwQJAiBQ5amW0p3O4CmWQTqPljejJ6iKFtH_HAJD1Qkt5jWUPp8A0",
}

payload = {"data": '{"H":"stocktickerhub","M":"GetAllStocks","A":[],"I":0}'}

data = requests.post(api_url, params=params, data=payload).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data["R"]["Stocks"].values())
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
       s                                          n      lp     c    pc       h       l      op         q     lv           t                    d    o      pl
0  SLBBL  Swarojgar Laghubitta Bittiya Sanstha Ltd.   650.0  10.0  1.56   652.0   640.0   650.0    4505.0   12.0   2896592.2  2024/01/25 02:59:41  260   640.0
1   PCBL                 Prime Commercial Bank Ltd.   209.4   1.5  0.72   209.9   206.0   209.9   53900.0   20.0  11230046.2  2024/01/25 02:59:57  196   207.9
2   LICN                   Life Insurance Co. Nepal  1389.1  -1.9 -0.14  1414.0  1388.6  1400.0    2418.0   50.0   3365832.2  2024/01/25 02:59:57  114  1391.0
3  MAKAR     Makar Jitumaya Suri Hydropower Limited   374.1  19.5  5.50   387.0   347.4   361.6  120451.0  219.0  44230220.0  2024/01/25 02:59:56  119   354.6
4  GBIME                    Global IME Bank Limited   202.0   0.3  0.15   202.9   199.0   200.0  113193.0   20.0  22820724.6  2024/01/25 02:59:58   57   201.7
```